# C++ - inheriting ostream crashes on android but not windows

Tags: android, c++, windows, io, iostream

I have implemented a simple ostream and streambuf class. For some reason, it crashes when I try to instantiate my AndroidLogOStream object.

Note: I have stlport_static in my Application.mk

```
class AndroidLogStreamBuf : public std::streambuf
    {
    public:
        inline AndroidLogStreamBuf() : std::streambuf()
        {
            //std::cout << "asdfg";

        }

        inline ~AndroidLogStreamBuf()
        {

        }



    };

    class AndroidLogOStream : public std::ostream
    {
    public:
        inline AndroidLogOStream() : std::ostream(&mBuf)
        {

        }

        inline ~AndroidLogOStream()
        {

        }

    private:
        AndroidLogStreamBuf mBuf;
    };
```

It's barebones, and it runs fine on windows. It compiles fine on android, but it crashes for some reason. The last line it tries to execute is in _streambuf.c:46:

```
template <class _CharT, class _Traits>
locale
basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::pubimbue(const locale& __loc) {
  this->imbue(__loc);          <---- crash
  locale __tmp = _M_locale;
  _M_locale = __loc;
  return __tmp;
}
```

Granted I am still quite confused on iostreams, but it must be something wrong with the constructor, I suppose it is not valid?

Comment: See [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/528661/440558) for some useful links.

Comment: why android and c++ tags? i can get the c++ one, but not the other!

Comment: I am running it on android with the android ndk :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a constructor, the base class is initialized first, followed by all of the members. When you call the base class constructor `std::ostream`, you're passing it the address of `mBuf`, which has not yet been constructed. Accessing an object that hasn't yet been constructed has undefined behaviour.

To get around this, you could redesign your classes as follows:

```
class AndroidLogStreamBuf : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    AndroidLogStreamBuf() : std::streambuf()
    { }

    ~AndroidLogStreamBuf()
    { }
};

class AndroidLogOStream : public std::ostream
{
public:
    AndroidLogOStream(AndroidLogStreamBuf *buf) :
        std::ostream(buf),
        mBuf(buf)
    { }

    ~AndroidLogOStream()
    { }

private:
    AndroidLogStreamBuf *mBuf;
};

class AndroidLogOStreamWithBuf
{
private:
    AndroidLogStreamBuf mBuf;
    AndroidLogOStream mStream;

public:
    AndroidLogOStreamWithBuf() :
        mBuf(&mStream),
        mStream()
    { }

    virtual ~AndroidLogOStreamWithBuf()
    { }

    AndroidLogOStream& getOStream()
    {
        return mStream;
    }
};
```

Notice the order I've declared `mBuf` and `mStream` in `AndroidLogOStreamWithBuf`: the two fields will be initialized in that order, regardless of the order they appear in the constructor initializer list. As an aside, marking the member functions as `inline` in your original code was superfluous: when you define a member function within the class definition, it's automatically marked as inlinable.

Whether this is a sensible design for your system depends on how you're intending to use these classes, but the answer is probably "no".

Comment: Ahhhh! that is a good point! One thing though: why does it run fine on windows?

Comment: One possible result of undefined behaviour is "running fine" unfortunately.

Comment: how would I go about solving this? I mean I need to pass the buffer as a refererence in the ostream constructor!

Comment: There, I've updated my answer with some more practical advice. I suspect the best solution for your situation will be different, depending on the design of the surrounding code.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out, the base class is constructed first and from the looks of it, the base class constructor seems to do something. I don't think it is meant to but the base class destructor would also create a problem and that will call `pubsync()` on the stream buffer.

Of course, this explains the problem but doesn't provide a solution: the solution to this initialization problem is to make the the stream buffer (or a custom class containing the stream buffer as member) a `virtual` base class:

```
class oandroidligstream:
    virtual AndroidLogStream,
    public std::ostringstream {
        ...
    }
};
```

the reason the base has to be virtual is that the stream buffer is an argument to the virtual base `std::ios`. To make sure your stream buffer is initialized first it has to be the left-most virtual base.

Comment: if I declare it virtual, it says 'mBuf is undefined' in my AndroidLogOStream ()  constructor, and I have to use mBuf in the constructor. How does one solve that?

Comment: Well it isn't a member anymore but a base class! You could use `this`. Alternatively you put it into a custom struct and use this a vitrual base.